# Обновление части странички в ajax

Tags: ajax, php

Как организовать автоматическое обновление (через 5-10 сек) части странички.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var intevalHandler = setInterval('reload()',7500); //Обновляется каждые 7500миллисекунд
```

Функция релоад должна содержать аякс запрос.
Полностью:
HTML:

```
<div id='updateMe'>
<span id='girl_name'>Маша</span> 
<span id='relationship'>любит</span> 
<span id='boy_name'>Васю</span> 
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var reloadFunction;
$(document).ready(function(){
  reloadFunction = function(){
    $.post('rel.php',{'some_query_var':'foobar'},function(data){
      data = eval('('+data+')');
      $("#girl_name").text(data.girl_name);
      $("#relationship").text(data.relationship);
      $("#boy_name").text(data.boy_name);
    });
   }
   var intevalHandler = setInterval('reloadFunction()',7500);
});
```

rel.php:

```
$girl_name = array('Маша','Лиза','Оля','Лена','Света');
$relationship = array('любит','не любит','плюнет в','поцелует','к сердцу прижмет');
$boy_name = array('Васю','Петю','Колю','Сашу','Федю');

$girl_rand_max = count($girl_name)-1;
$relationship_rand_max = count($relationship)-1;
$boy_rand_max = count($boy_name)-1;
printf('{"girl_name":"%s","relationship":"%s","boy_name":"%s"}',$girl_name[rand(0,$girl_rand_max)],$relationship[rand(0,$relationship_rand_max)],$boy_name[rand(0,$boy_rand_max)]);
```

Если ничего не накосячил, должно работать.

Comment: А можете пожалуйста полностью скрипт/пример, там где должен быть скрипт php помете пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо +1, не ожидал что так быстро получу помощь и качественно.

Comment: Неужели оно с первого раза запустилось? )))

Comment: Если человек догадался подключить jQuery, то должно сработать с первого раза)))

Comment: Вот как сделал index.html
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
  $.post('rel.php',{'some_query_var':'foobar'},function(data){
    data = eval('('+data+')');
    $("#girl_name").text(data.girl_name);
    $("#relationship").text(data.relationship);
    $("#boy_name").text(data.boy_name);
  });
});</script>
<div id='updateMe'>
<span id='girl_name'>Маша</span> 
<span id='relationship'>любит</span> 
<span id='boy_name'>Васю</span> 
</div>, оно видает Маша любит Васю , но обновление странички не происходит =(. Может что-то я тупанул

Comment: Это я тупанул. Я не вставил в код set_interval. См исправленный вариант. =) Так должно быть лучше.

Comment: Аааа =) Да мы такие, недогадливые. 1.6.1.jquery.min.js Пойдет?

Comment: Пойдет любой с 1.4+
С более низкими советую не связываться.
Такой вариант ТОЧНО работает. ТОлько что проверил

Answer (score 2):

AJAX

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script>  
    function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "time.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#content").html(html);  
            }  
        });  
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',1000);  
    });  
</script>
```

в блоке content будет выводиться скрипт time.php И обновляться - setInterval('show()',1000);